# find most occuring combined words

Tags: r, nlp

I am trying to get text analysis done for a set of a set of short descriptions:

```
Short description
Login failed for user
login failed
Authentication for login failed
server unavailable ping failure
Server unavailable
server not starting
```

and im trying to find the maxiumum occured issue.
I am applying the below
after creating the appropriate corpus,

```
dataset = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
dataset$Liked = sdr$Liked
dataset = as.matrix(dtm)
v = sort(colSums(dataset),decreasing=TRUE)
myNames = names(v)
d = data.frame(word=myNames,freq=v)
```

The output here gives me a single word count frequency.
I want to find the occurences where the words came together.
My expected output is

```
login failed         2
server unavailable   2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you add output of `dput(dtm)`?

Comment: Wouldn't just `table` help? If `df` is your dataframe, `sort(table(df$Shortdescription), decreasing = TRUE)` ?

Comment: In addition to @RonakShah throw a `tolower` around it. `table(tolower(df$Shortdescription))`.

Comment: ill change the scenario to a slightly different case. This is what im trying to imply. please read my input again. now with different other words too, the common words need to come around.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a test string and count `length`s with a `sapply`.

```
test <- c("login failed", "server unavailable")
sapply(test, function(x) length(grep(x, tolower(dat$short))))
# login failed server unavailable 
#            3                  2
```

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(short = structure(c(7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L
), .Label = c("Authentication for login failed", "login failed", 
"Login failed for user", "server not starting", "Server unavailable", 
"server unavailable ping failure", "Short description"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```